# Understanding a proof that a Hermitian matrix has an orthonormal basis whose diagonal contains its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

**Context.** Accoring to pg. 36 of *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*:

> [image]

My confusion surrounds the nature of the portions of the proof highlighted in red.

**Notation.** It seems to me the proof potentially conflates two distinct matrices and kets.

- First, we have the $n$-dimensional matrix $\Omega$ vs. the $n-1$-dimensional matrix $\Omega_{n-1}$, which is the lower right subset of $\Omega$ (as outlined in the proof).
- Next we have the $n-1$-dimensional $|\omega_2 \rangle_{n-1}$, which can be expressed as $(\omega_2, 0, \ldots, 0)$ against the basis $\{| \omega_2 \rangle_{n-1}, \ldots \}$. This should be contrasted with $|\omega_2 \rangle_n$, which the author *implicitly asserts* (but unless I'm missing something: doesn't establish) can be expressed as $(0, \omega_2, 0, \ldots, 0)$ against the basis $\{|\omega_1 \rangle, |\omega_2\rangle_n, \ldots \}$.

**Problem.** It seems to me that the author has established only that

$$
\Omega_{n-1} | \omega_2 \rangle_{n-1} = \omega_2 |\omega_2 \rangle_{n-1}
$$

But why does that imply that

$$
\Omega_{n} | \omega_2 \rangle_{n} = \omega_2 |\omega_2 \rangle_{n}
$$

..which is what it seems the author actually needs to show in order for his proof to work?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your misgivings about the proof presented. I believe that the proof can be clarified with a more careful consideration of the relationship between an operator and [its matrix relative to some basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#The_matrix_of_a_linear_transformation).

It is not specified in the statement or proof, but I'll assume that $\Omega$ is an operator on the space $\Bbb C^n$. In the first part of the proof, the author constructs the orthonormal basis
$$
\mathcal B_1^n = \{|\omega_1\rangle, V^1_{\perp 1}, \dots, V^{n-1}_{\perp1}\}.
$$
The superscript $n$ merely indicates that this is a basis for the $n$-dimensional space $\Bbb C^n$. Relative to this basis, $[\Omega]_{\mathcal B_1^n}$ has the form indicated in Equation (1.8.12). This implies that the set
$$
U_1 = |\omega_1\rangle^\perp = \operatorname{span}\{V^1_{\perp 1}, \dots, V^{n-1}_{\perp1}\} \subset \Bbb C^n
$$
is an **invariant subspace** of $\Omega$. In other words, for any vector $|v\rangle \in U_1$, $\Omega |v\rangle$ will also be an element of $U_1$. With that in mind, we may consider the **restriction** of $\Omega$ to this subspace, which I will denote as $\Omega|_{U_1}: U_1 \to U_1$. This simply refers to the map defined by
$$
\Omega|_{U_1} |v \rangle = \Omega|v\rangle,
$$
with the caveat that $|v\rangle$ is required to be an element of $U_1$. From $\mathcal B_1^n$, we "inherit" a basis for $U_1$:
$$
\mathcal B_1^{n-1} = \{V^1_{\perp 1}, \dots, V^{n-1}_{\perp1}\}.
$$
I claim that the matrix of $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B_1^{n-1}}$ is equal to the "boxed submatrix" indicated in the proof. I would suggest that you try to prove that this is the case for yourself. Because $\Omega|_{U_1}$ is also Hermitian, we consider an eigenvalue $\omega_2$ of $\Omega|_{U_1}$ to construct a new orthonormal basis of $U_1$,
$$
\mathcal B_{2}^{n-1} = \{|\omega_2 \rangle, V_{\perp1,2}^1,\dots,V^{n-2}_{\perp1,2}\}.
$$
Note that each of these vectors from the basis are elements of $U_1$ and hence elements of $\Bbb C^n$. In particular, this eigenvector $|\omega_2\rangle$ satisfies
$$
\Omega|_{U_1} |\omega_2 \rangle = \Omega|\omega_2 \rangle = \omega_2 |\omega_2 \rangle.
$$
That is, $|\omega_2\rangle$ is not only an eigenvector of the restricted operator $\Omega|_{U_1}$, but also of the full operator $\Omega$ over $\Bbb C^n$.
The matrix of $\Omega|_{U_1}$ relative to this basis has the block-diagonal form
$$
[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B^{n-1}_{2}} = 
\pmatrix{
\omega_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \star & \cdots & \star\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \star & \cdots & \star }.
$$
Now, this basis can be extended to the orthonormal basis
$$
\mathcal B_2^{n} = \{|\omega_1\rangle,|\omega_2 \rangle, V_{\perp1,2}^1,\dots,V^{n-2}_{\perp1,2}\}.
$$
I claim that the matrix $[\Omega]_{\mathcal B_2^n}$ has the above-mentioned matrix $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B_2^{n-1}}$ as a submatrix. Thus, the matrix of $\Omega$ relative to $\mathcal B_2^n$ has the form
$$
[\Omega]_{\mathcal B_2^n} = 
\pmatrix{
\omega_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \omega_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \star & \cdots & \star\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \star & \cdots & \star }.
$$

Comment: I have thought about, and remain confused by the claims that (i) the matrix of $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B_1^{n-1}}$ is equal to the "boxed submatrix" indicated in the proof and (ii) the matrix of $\Omega|_{U_1}$ relative to this basis has the block-diagonal form $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B^{n-1}_{2}} = \ldots$. In particular, it seems like you shift in and out of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$. For example, the matrix $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B^{n-1}_{2}} = \ldots$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional matrix, meaning its domain and codomain is $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Does the claim that "the matrix of $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B_1^{n-1}}$ is equal to the 'boxed submatrix' indicated in the proof" have a name (so I can inspect proofs online)?  Thanks for your help. I feel like I'm on the cusp of understanding things but not quite there :]

Comment: @user1770201 The fact that $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B_2^{n-1}}$ has size $n-1$ does **not** mean that $\Omega|_{U_1}$ is an operator on $\Bbb C^n$. In fact, $\Omega|_{U_1}$ is an operator over $U_1$, which is a subspace of $\Bbb C^n$ (of dimension $n-1$). As I say in my post, all vectors that I refer to in my post are elements of $\Bbb C^n$. There is no "shifting in and out of $\Bbb C^{n-1}$".

Comment: @user1770201 Regarding your second comment, there is no name for this statement that I am aware of

Comment: @user1770201 Sorry that first sentence should read "...does **not** mean that $\Omega|_{U_1}$ is an operator on $\color{red}{\Bbb C^{n-1}}$".

Comment: Ben: $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B^{n-1}_{2}}$ being an $(n-1)$-dimensional ѕquare matrix, yet being applied to $n$-dimensional elements from $\mathbb{C}^n$ is what is confusing me.  Is that "legal"?

Comment: @u It is not the matrix that is being applied to these vectors; the operator $\Omega|_{U_1}$ is being applied to these vectors.

Comment: How is it that $\Omega|_{U_1}$ can be identified with the $(n-1)$-dimensional matrix $[\Omega|_{U_1}]_{\mathcal B^{n-1}_{2}}$ when $\Omega|_{U_1}$ is applied on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: @user1770201 It's not applied on all of $\Bbb C^n$, only the subspace $U_1$